# how to display another column not by id java spring mvc?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, controller

i have 2 table 
 pegawai table and absensi table
i have issue .. i cant display id from pegawai table when i select it by nip

this is my table picture

[image: relation table]

my view code :

```
<input type="text" name="nip" id="nip">
```

my implement code :

```
 @Override
public ResultSet getByNip(String nip) {        
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) em.createQuery("select a.id from Pegawai a WHERE a.nip='"+nip+"'");
    return rs;
}
```

my controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ProsesAbsensi.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String prosesAbsensi(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletResponse response,
         @RequestMapping(value = "ProsesAbsensi.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String prosesAbsensi(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute("Absensi") Absensi a,
        @RequestParam(value = "nip", required = false) String nip
) throws SQLException, IOException {
    PegawaiImplement pi = new PegawaiImplement();
    ResultSet rs = pi.getByNip(nip);
    AbsensiImplement ai = new AbsensiImplement();
    ai.insert(a);
    return "Depan";

}
```

how do i get id from pegawai table into my controller ?

Comment: Your problem, is you are not adding any object to the model view, so you cant access it later. be sure you add the proper object to the modelMap attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend to improve your design. As I see you are using Spring and JPA. In this case I'd suggest to take a look at Spring Data JPA: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

With this you'd end up with following code in your service layer

```
public Pegawai getByNip(String nip) {        
   return pegawaiRepository.findByNip(nip);
}
```

In your controller you simply write

```
service.getByNip(nip).getId()
```

in order to get the ID.

If you can't do this (for whatever reason), you would use your entity manager to create a query (no result set). You can get examples here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html. In your case:

```
em.createQuery("select a.id from Pegawai a WHERE a.nip='"+nip+"'").getSingleResult();
```

Comment: You're totally welcome. Which approach did you choose? Spring Data JPA?